How to add a Custom Search Engine to Google Chrome that searches Microsoft Copilot
When using Google Chrome, I would like to add a Custom Search Engine with a keyword of "co" that sends the words typed in after "co" to be sent to Copilot as a so-called "new topic". I do not want to have to do this in two steps, first going to https://copilot.microsoft.com/ and then moving the mouse cursor to find the text entry field and then type it in.
I know how to add a custom search engine for, say, Amazon in Google Chrome. The URL will have the %s string embedded in it, and it works. E.g., the URL for searching Amazon would be:
https://www.amazon.com/s?k=%s

Now, I desire to create a custom search engine instead for Copilot at:
https://copilot.microsoft.com/
But using this as the site search does not work:
https://copilot.microsoft.com/?q=%s

Trying it out via:

yields a URL of:
https://copilot.microsoft.com/?q=what+is+the+average+lifetime+of+a+household+cat

but that link just ends up with a blank text entry field:

Is there a way to do this?

You can try adding it using the Bing Chat web address (which - unlike Copilot direct - uses the search term in the URL:
https://www.bing.com/chat?form=RSCODX&sendquery=1&q=%s



Verified that does exactly what I had intended! Much thanks to you!
